# Appending to div and being unable to bind the added buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a php function that echos code of a form that has a button. when that button is click it will append a file field and a another button that if clicked would repeat the above. however when the added button is clicked nothing happened.

I am thinking it has something to do with binding the button.

Here is the code:

```
$formtoreturn = '
<div class="form_holder">
    <form action="'.site_url().'xxxxx" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >


    <div id="fields_holder">
        <span class="form_holder-label" id="fileC">Select image or images</span> 
        <div class="fields" id="field1">
            <input type="file" name="fileID-input[]" id="fileID-input" class="fileC-input">
            <a rel="add" id="add_file1" class="add_file" href="javascript:;"><img src="wp-content/plugins/wl_extendor_wishlist/images/add-icon.png"></a>
        </div>

    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>

    <input type="hidden" value="'.$u_id.'" name="user_id" id="user_id">
    <input type="submit" name="submittestimonial" value="Submit Testimonial">
    </form>
    <iframe id="upload_target" name="upload_target" src="#" style="width:0;height:0;border:0px solid #fff;"></iframe>
</div>
<script>
var filecount = 1;
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
$j(document).ready(function() {
    $j(\'#fields_holder\').on(\'click\', \'.add_file\', function() {
        var toappend = \'<div class="fields" id="field1"><input type="file" name="fileID-input[]" id="fileID-input" class="fileC-input"><a rel="add" id="add_file1" class="add_file" href="javascript:;"><img src="wp-content/plugins/wl_extendor_wishlist/images/add-icon.png"></a></div>\';

        if($j(this).attr("rel") == "add"){
            $j(this).attr("rel", "ded");
            $j("#fields_holder").append(toappend);
            filecount++;
        }
    });
});

</script>
';
echo $formtoreturn;
```

Hope the code and my question is clear.

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: It's not very clean to echo such a large block of html using php, you should look into php templating engines like Smarty and the like. It will save you a lot of pain!

Comment: The second time, which button are you clicking? Notice YOU are clearly disabling the previous buttons and only allowing the last one to add new fields

Comment: php its self is sort of template language using another later shouldn't be the different. but thanks for help

Comment: Alexander by the second time clicking the button i mean the second button that was added - that was a big misleading sorry i will correct that.

Comment: @NetaMeta, then the [code works as expected](http://jsfiddle.net/z43J8/)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to change your JavaScript code from

```
$j('#fields_holder').on('click', '.add_file', function() {
     // ...
});
```

to

```
$j(document).on('click', '#fields_holder .add_file', function() {
     // ...
});
```

Then the event will bubble up and handled in click handler of a `document`.

**UPDATE**

Though I've made a [**test**](http://jsfiddle.net/f0t0n/4E2Au/) and it's working well for me in both variants.

Comment: Tried with document even tried  but why would i change add_flie (which is the button being clicked) to fields_holder which is the div containing the buttons and isnt being clicked